# How to use .filter() to return a match inside of an array (rethinkdb)

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to find out how many of my students are being taught by a specific teacher. However some of the students have multiple teachers. The value of the `teacher_name` entry is represented as an array. The following query only shows those results where the match is exact, that is, it won't show me results where there are multiple teachers.

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter({teacher_name: ["Andrew McSwain"]});
```

How can I iterate through the arrays to match if it contains the string I specified? Is there an API command for this or can I use good-ole javascript methods?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter(function(row) {
  return row('teacher_name').contains('Andrew McSwain');
})
```

Comment: didn't work. returned error code: e: Cannot convert STRING to SEQUENCE in:
r.db("client").table("basic_info").filter(function(var_28) { return var_28("teacher_name").contains("Andrew McSwain"); })

Comment: That probably means you have at least one row in your table where `teacher_name` is a string instead of an array.  The easiest way to fix that is to make all such entries have `teacher_name` be an array of one element.